# In spark mllib, can LogisticRegressionWithSGD do multiple classification tasks?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib, logistic-regression

I want to use `LogisticRegressionWithSGD` to do multiple classification tasks, but there is no `setNumClasses` method in `org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionWithSGD`. I know that `LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS` can do multiple classification tasks, but why `LogisticRegressionWithSGD` cann't ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiclass classification using `LogisticRegressionWithSGD()` is not supported, though it is a requested feature: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10179 . It was decided not to add this feature since `SparkML` will be the main Machine Learning API for Spark in future, not `Spark Mllib`.

Comment: How to use SparkML ? I can not find any document or programming guides on Internet.

Comment: from official docs : http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#logistic-regression. SparkML examples : https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/ml

Comment: I have the same problem with getting LogisticRegressionWithSGD() to work with over two classes.  However, the documentation from https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html would suggest that Multinomial Logistic Regression is possible:

numClasses – The number of possible outcomes for k classes classification problem in Multinomial Logistic Regression. By default, it is binary logistic regression so numClasses will be set to 2.